# How to precache a font that is used by css font-face rule that includes a query parameter in its URL value?

Tags: css, fonts, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I'm using Workbox(V5) and in my *workbox-config.js* I precached the fonts (*.woff* and *.woff2* formats) that are needed for the 3rd-party CSS styles that I'm using, by specifying this for the `globPatterns` property:

```
// workbox-config.js

module.exports = {
  globDirectory: './',
  globPatterns: [
    '**/*.{html,ico,woff,woff2}',
  ],
  globIgnores: [
    'node_modules/**/*',
    '{.,_}*/**/*',
    '**/*.{md,txt}',
    'Gemfile*',
    'package*',
  ],
  additionalManifestEntries: [
    {
      url: './manifest.webmanifest',
      revision: null, // I have also precached my manifest file like this. Is it the best practice?
    },
  ],
  swDest: './sw.js',
  sourcemap: false,
};
```

Now in the *.css* file of the 3rd-party, I can see that the needed fonts are being used with the `@font-face` rule that includes a query parameter in its URL value:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "bootstrap-icons";
  src: url("./fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff?4601c71fb26c9277391ec80789bfde9c") format("woff"),
       url("./fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff2?4601c71fb26c9277391ec80789bfde9c") format("woff2");
}
```

Well, if I remove the generated hash that has been added to the URL, when I run my PWA offline, the precached fonts show up just fine... But when the styles are calling the fonts with the hash, the precached fonts won't show up!

I have also tried to precache the fonts in my HTML file's head tag and the do runtimeCaching for the *.woff* and *.woff2* formats instead of precaching them by the `globPatterns` property, but still no luck!

```
<link rel="preload" as="font" href="./assets/styles/vendor/fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="preload" as="font" href="./assets/styles/vendor/fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff2" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

So I was wondering how can we fix this problem?

Thanks a heap,
Ali

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`ignoreURLParametersMatching`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-build#:%7E:text=ignoreURLParametersMatching) configuration option when generating your service worker to tell `workbox-precaching` that certain URL parameters can be ignored when checking the cache for a match.

The parameter takes an array of `RegExp`s, and the default is `[/^utm_/, /^fbclid$/]`, which matches some common analytics tracking parameters.

In your particular case, it sounds like the values you want to ignore are all 32 hex characters, so the following configuration should help:

```
// workbox-config.js

module.exports = {
  ignoreURLParametersMatching: [/^[0-9a-f]{32}$/],
  // ...other options go here...
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @jeff-posnick for the tip. But I was also wondering is it possible to do runtimeCaching for the fonts without precaching them and without our HTML file calling to load them inside of the head tag? I mean is it also possible to cache fonts that are referenced inside of the css files by the font-face rule, once the css gets loaded?

Comment: Sure. Checking `request.destination === 'font'` would be the "correct" way to do that, i.e. `registerRoute(({request}) => request.destination === 'font', new CacheFirst({cacheName: 'fonts'}))`

Comment: Thanks! And another way to do that, if we're using the `workbox-cli` and like to run `workbox generateSW workbox-config.js` command in order to generate our service-worker rather than writing it manually, is this: Seting a runtimeCaching in our `workbox-config.js` with our unique regular expression pattern to support loading fonts with or without URL parameters: `{ urlPattern: /\.(?:woff2|woff)(\?[0-9a-f]{1,32})?$/, handler: 'CacheFirst', options: { cacheName: 'fonts' } }`

Comment: `runtimeCaching: [{
  urlPattern: ({request}) => request.destination === 'font',
  handler: 'CacheFirst',
}, {
  /* other routes go here */
}]`